# Unable to determine root cause for com.tridion.util.TCMURI ClassNotFoundException

Tags: content-delivery, dynamic-linking

I have already included `Tridion.ContentDelivery.dll` in the bin folder with a Reference in `Web.config`

```
<add tagPrefix="tridion" namespace="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.UI"
     assembly="Tridion.ContentDelivery"/>
```

Even with this reference, when rendering a Component Link in my .NET Application I get a ClassNotFoundException. Can anybody help me to determine root cause for this?

> com.tridion.util.TCMURI
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.util.TCMURI
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.util.TCMURI]
>   Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst) +373
>   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst) +1365
>   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.init() +361
>   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.get_JObject() +49
>   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init() +1082
>   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_MethodPtr() +54
>   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_Handle() +50
>   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args) +368
>   Com.Tridion.Util.TCMURI..ctor(String uri) +127
>   Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.UI.ComponentLink.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +146
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +208
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +8
>   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +208
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +173
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +31
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +53
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +40
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +208
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +8
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +31
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +208
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +8
>   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +208
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +8
>   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3060

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a JAVA class, not a .NET class.

I'd recommend finding your Tridion installation files, search for `[Install]\Content Delivery\roles\preview\web\dotNet\webapp` folder, then compare your web application to either the x86.zip or x86_64.zip pre-built webapps.

Chances are you're missing a couple of jars.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nuno. There was unwanted CMS side dll present in folder which might have been conflicting the references!!